# Apache2 SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG behind proxy

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4

My web server is configured to use Let's Encryt certificate and I'm continuously getting the error SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG when trying to access some of my subdomains (with same certificate) from a specific network (my co-working space).

I have 4 subdomains that are working and the rest (4 others) aren't. Each domain is using a Virtual host like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin nicolas@covevent.be
        ServerName app.covevent.be

    DocumentRoot /home/covevent/app
    <Directory /home/covevent/app>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>



<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin nicolas@covevent.be
        ServerName app.covevent.be

    DocumentRoot /home/covevent/app
    <Directory /home/covevent/app> 
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.covevent.be/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.covevent.be/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The configuration is exactly the same for api.covevent.be, www.covevent.be etc.
Do you see something wrong in this configuration ?

I checked and accessing http://www.covevent.be:443 doesn't work and is blocked by Apache. Also SSL is enabled as my other domains are working...

Comment: Is mod_ssl actually loaded? It is as if your web server spoke plain HTTP on port 443.

Comment: Yes it is as everything is working fine from other places (home for instance)

Comment: Are the hostnames resolving to the correct IP address(es) when you're at your co-working space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> accessing http://www.covevent.be:443 doesn't work

And rightly so. Port 443 is the port for https not http and the Apache config you show correctly configures https at port 443. Thus `http://www.covevent.be:443` will not work but `https://www.covevent.be:443` (i.e. https instead of http) will work as will a simple `https://www.covevent.be` because 443 is the default port for https.

> I'm continuously getting the error SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG when trying to access some of my subdomains ... from a specific network ...

The error indicates that you are using https and not http as you've shown in your link. Based on your description the error happens only from a specific network where a proxy is used. This is probably due to the proxy intercepting TLS connections and blocking access to this site for whatever reason. In this case you need to ask the IT administrator responsible for the proxy for help so that the site does not get blocked any longer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer http://www.covevent.be:443 was a test to show that Apache is not servicing http over https (some google searches suggested that). What's bothering me is that some of my subdomains are working and some not, with the exact same configurations in the vhosts.

Comment: @Gp2mv3: again, if this is only inside a specific network then it is a problem related to this network and you should ask the IT administrator there. The error you see can happen if the site is blocked by a SSL intercepting proxy.

Comment: @Gp2mv3 what you read is nonsense, when you use "http://" you are telling the browser to use non-SSL, since your website has SSL enabled in port 443, trying to use http is futile and useless.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes it seem to be related to the network itself but it's weird that it's working for my other domains... Will ask the administrator. Thanks for your answer !

Comment: @ezra-s It's explained there for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119336/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-and-apache-ssl

Comment: @Gp2mv3 I don't see there anyone telling to do http://something:443. Anyways, there is not much discussion, if Apache has ports assigned to their default behaviour 443 will be SSL and port 80 will be non-SSL.